# How many addresses can be assigned to one network interface via DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

Are there any limits to how many addresses can be assigned to one client DHCP host from DHCP server? 
Can I assign whole /8 subnet to one interface via DHCP?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any limits to how many addresses can be assigned to one client DHCP host from DHCP server?

## IPv6

No. An IPv6 DHCP server can advertise any prefix size to clients that request prefix delegation.

## IPv4

In most common scenarios only **one for each interface** as  the DHCP response is based on the MAC address of the requesting NIC and AFAIK only designed to carry a single IP-address

Having said that, from the client you can request  more than one ip-address , with a bit of additional configuration, as the reference ISC DHCP client does support the creation of a "pseudo" interface, with which you can request a single extra address for each pseudo interface that you create.

[`man dhclient.conf`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf)

> **`pseudo`** `"name" "real-name" { declarations ... }`
>
> Under some circumstances it can be useful to declare a pseudo-interface and have the DHCP client acquire a configuration for that interface. Each interface that the DHCP client is supporting normally has a DHCP client state machine running on it to acquire and maintain its lease. A **pseudo-interface is just another state machine** running on the interface named real-name, with its **own lease** and its **own state**.
>
> If you use this feature, you must provide a client identifier for both the pseudo-interface and the actual interface, and the two identifiers must be different. You must also provide a separate client script for the pseudo-interface to do what you want with the IP address. For example:
>
> ```
>   interface "ep0" {
>         send dhcp-client-identifier "my-client-ep0";
>    }
>    pseudo "secondary" "ep0" {
>         send dhcp-client-identifier "my-client-ep0-secondary";
>         script "/etc/dhclient-secondary";
>    }
> ```
>
> The client script for the pseudo-interface should not configure the interface up or down - essentially, all it needs to handle are the states where a lease has been acquired or renewed, and the states where a lease has expired. See [`dhclient-script(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient-script) for more information.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference to a suitable IPv4 'separate client script' that would run `ip address add` and `ip address del` to add and remove the secondary address to the interface?