# Obtaining two DHCP addresses on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, dhcp, dhcp-server

There have been various questions asked a long time ago about obtaining two IP addresses via DHCP on Linux. Most of those are still relating to old 'alias interfaces', like `eth0:0`, which has been deprecated for a long time.

As referenced in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/959375/how-many-addresses-can-be-assigned-to-one-network-interface-via-dhcp), it should be possible to get multiple IP addresses by using `send dhcp-client-identifier` with different values, and indeed there is a partial example of this in the manual page for `dhclient.conf`

But that refers to "you must also provide a separate client script for the pseudo-interface" to configure it. Such a script would presumably need to run `ip address add` and `ip address del` for the secondary IP address when the DHCP client reaches the right states.

Is there any example anywhere out there of a working version of such a script? And will it work with the default script for the primary address (which seems to be very enthusiastic in deleting any and all other IP addresses on the interface)

Has anyone ever got such a setup to work?

Comment: The enthusiasm is from the kernel, not a script: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n1661

Comment: If you are referring to the `promote_secondaries` flag, then that does the opposite - it retains a secondary IP when the primary is removed. I'm referring to lines like `ip -4 addr flush dev ${interface} label ${interface}` in `/sbin/dhclient-script`, which will flush all IP addresses on an interface when the interface gets a `BOUND`, `RENEW`, `REBIND` or `REBOOT` event in some cases. It may be that the script arguments are always such that the line does not get called, but it is hard to tell.